# Delphi Android Memory Leak(or another slowdown)

Tags: android, delphi, memory-leaks, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I'm opening a new form. It's getting slower each time when opening it.I try FormClose event FreeAndnil, Free, Release, DisposeOf but not solution. I've added a standby timer:

Button1 first Click, After Form 2 show 0,18 Second

Button1 Second Click, After Form 2 show 0,20 Second

Button1 Third Click, After Form 2 show 0,23 Second

Button1 fourth  Click, After Form 2 show 0,28 Second
.
.
.

Button1 xxxx Click, After Form 2 show 6,30 Second

```
     //Form1 Button1 Click 
 Application.CreateForm(TFrom2,Form2);
  Form2.Show;


//Form2 OnCLose
//i try 
//FreeAndNil, Free, Relsease,DisposeOf ...
```

How to solve this?
Sample Project Source :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yeqpizr6rfo6254/LeakProblem.rar

Try 20-30 times Click "Form2 Show Button"
See increase wait time in memo.

Comment: What makes you think this slowdown is down to a memory leak?

Comment: Without any code and proof, I think you're right about the "leak". The Form you create via `Application.CreateForm(..)` does not get freed because `Application` still holds a reference to it. What if you don't use `Application.CreateForm(..)` and do a `myForm := TForm2.Create(Nil)` instead?

Comment: Apllication.CreateForm is my habitude. i try now TForm2.Create(nil)

Comment: Andy_D Memory leak or another. i dont know

Comment: @ Günther the Beautiful i try but not change wait times.

Comment: i find the problem. problem is Stylebook Component. i remove Stylebok component on my form wait times stable. but i want use Stylebook :(

Comment: if i remove Stylebook compoent on form not fix but wait timesslightly shorter.
but not resolved...

Comment: In case there's a really good reason to not just create a single instance on Startup and re-use it: Can you please post your complete `onClick` handler? Also, you should probably add the 'delphi' tag to your question, not just `Delphi-xe5'

Comment: My OnClick Handler in my first post only .

Comment: i added sample code on first post.

Comment: Fun fact: On iOS the provided project crashes (screen freezes) with less than 5 show/hides. The time to show also increases steadily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I messed around with your project a little and got it working, but there's a lot of things that you do differently than how I normally program.

For starters, when disposing of a form in mobile you want to use .DisposeOf, not FreeAndNil. See [this link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Automatic_Reference_Counting_in_Delphi_Mobile_Compilers#The_Free_and_DisposeOf_methods_under_ARC), especially:

> there are scenarios when you need to execute the destructor code right
>   away, regardless of the fact that there might be other pending
>   references to the object. [...]  the new compiler introduces a dispose
>   pattern: `MyObject.DisposeOf`;

Another thing I noticed is that your Unit3 creates Form4. But then you have Unit4 accessing the memo in Unit3. I hope that's just for demo purposes as I don't think that sort of design is suggested.

So, short summary of how I got it to work: I set up a `TNotifyEvent` in Form4 for when it is finished:

```
procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if assigned(FOnCloseEvent) then
    FOnCloseEvent(Self);
end;
```

In Uni3, I setup a handler when the form is created:

```
  MyForm.OnCloseEvent := CloseEvent;
```

The event triggers this code:

```
procedure TForm3.CloseEvent(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if assigned(MyForm) then
    MyForm.DisposeOf;
end;
```

I also made `MyForm` a private object of `TForm3` as opposed to local variable.

With these changes I can hit show and close as long as I want and the form will always show quickly. There could be better ways to do this, if there are let me know!

Comment: Thanks For your samples. but i m do not apply your suggestion on my application. Please share me sample source code ? Thank you.

Comment: Please share me a multilpe forms sample,i install my application for my customer and  I'm very difficult position. Thank you for all

Comment: Well, if you don't want to use the advice I gave, just try to free the form using .DisposeOf **outside** of the class that you are trying to free. I think the main problem with your code is trying to free the form from inside the object itself.